# selecting text from a middle of a textfile with known line numbers

Tags: r

I wrote some R code to run analysis on my research project. I coded it in such a way that there was an output text file with the status of the program. Now the header of the output file looks like this:

```
start time: 2014-10-23 19:15:04 
starting analysis on state model: 16 
current correlation state: 1 
>>>em_prod_combs 
em_prod_combs 
H3K18Ac_H3K4me1 1.040493e-50 
H3K18Ac_H3K4me2 3.208806e-77 
H3K18Ac_H3K4me3 0.0001307375 
H3K18Ac_H3K9Ac 0.001904384
```

the `>>>em_prod_combs" is on line 4. line 5 its repeated again (R code). I'd like data from like 6. This data goes on for 36 more rows so ends at line 42.  Then there is some other text in the file until all the way to like 742 which looks like this:

```
 (742) >>>em_prod_combs 
 (743) em_actual_perc 
 (744) H3K18Ac_H3K4me1 0 
H3K18Ac_H3K4me2 0 
H3K18Ac_H3K4me3 0.0001976819 
H3K18Ac_H3K9Ac 0.001690382
```

And again I'd like to select data from line 744 (actual data, not headers) and go for another 36 rows and end at line 780. Here is my part of the code:

```
filepath <- paste(folder_directory, corr_folders[fi], filename, sep="" )
     con <- file(filepath) 
     open(con);
     results.list <- list();
     current.line <- 0
     while (length(line <- readLines(con, n = 1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {
       if(line==">>>em_prod_combs"){
         storethenext <- TRUE
       }
     } 
     close(con)
```

Here, I was trying to see if the line read had the ">>>" mark. If so, set a variable to TRUE and store the next 36 lines (using another counter variable) in a data frame or list and set the `storethenext` variable back to `F`. I was kind of hoping that there is a better way of doing this....

Comment: in such situations, I usually use `readLines` on the whole file, then `grep` the marks to isolate the blocks of interest.

Comment: `g <- grep(">>>", r <- readLines(file), fixed=TRUE)+1` to find the line that follows the unwanted line. Then `r[g]` should get you the result

Comment: Sorry, not the result...the starting point of each block

Comment: Hi@RichardScriven, I can find the starting of each block. Just looking for a easy way to read the next 36 lines without using nested for loops, if statements and counter variable

Comment: How about `read.table(text=r[start.line:end.line])` ?

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed with a slight modification. Check my answer below. If you can write your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

So I realized that ReadLines has a parameter that you can set for skipping lines. Based on that, I got this:

```
df <- data.frame(name = character, 
                 params = numeric(40),                               
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

con <- file(filepath) 
open(con);
results.list <- list();
current.line <- 0
firstblock <- readLines(con, n = 5, warn = FALSE)
firstblock <- NULL #throwaway
firstblock <- readLines(con, n = 36, warn = FALSE)
firstblock <- as.list(firstblock) #convert to list
for(k in 1:36){
  splitstring = strsplit(firstblock[[k]], " ", fixed=TRUE)
  ## put the data in the df
}
```

But it turns out from Ben's answer that read.table can do the same thing in one line: So I've reduced it down to the following one liner:

```
firstblock2 <- read.table(filepath, header = FALSE, sep = " ", skip = 5, nrows = 36)
```

This also makes it a data frame impliticitly and does all the dirty work for me.
The documentation for read.table is here:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html

Answer (score 0):

In `tidyverse` *(`readr`)*
If you don't wish to convert the data into a dataframe you can just read the slice of text with `read_lines()`
  (being sure to note that the `n_max =` argument is asking for how many lines you want to read in; not the number of the row you want to stop at. tbh: Ultimately I too found this preferable as usually I need to manage the file length more than I need to isolate sections of code on the read in.)

```
firstblock <- read_lines(filepath, skip = 5, n_max = 31)
```

If you don't want to think in terms of file size, you could modify your code thus:

```
start_line = 5
end_line = 36
line_count = end_line - start_line

firstblock <- read_lines(filepath, skip = start_line, n_max = line_count)
```

In any case, additional things I found helpful for working with these file formats after I got to know them a little better after finding this post before:

If you want to convert files immediately into lists as you did above just use:

```
read_lines_raw(filepath, skip = 5, n_max = 31)
```

and you will get a 31 element list as your firstblock element in lieu of the character element that you get with the first.

Additional super-cool features I stumbled upon there (and was moved to share - because I thought they rock):

- automatically decompresses* `.gz`, `.bz2`, `.xz`, or `.zip` files.
- will make the connection and complete the download automatically if the filepath starts with `http://`, `https://`, `ftp://`, or `ftps://`.
- If the file has both an extension and prefix as above, then it does both.

If things need to go back where they came from, the `write_lines` function turned out to be much more enjoyable to use that the base version. specifically, there are no FileConn's to open and close: just specify the object, and the filename you wish to write it into.

so for example the below:

```
fileConn <- file("directory/new.sql")
writeLines(new_sql, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

gets to just be:

```
write_lines(new_sql, "directory/new.sql")
```

Enjoy, and hope this helps!